# python replace dataframe column values with additional column concatenation

Tags: python, indexing, replace, concatenation

I have a df output generated from multiple columns (example below):

```
     col_a     col_b     col_c
0     101       104       AAB
1     337       103       CAD
2     524       204       DER
3     129       404       EEH
4     842       108       HHR
5     337       108       HHE
```

Is there anyway in python I can replace col_a values such that if any value is 101 or 337 or 524, col_a values become concatenated to whatever its corresponding col_b and col_c values are?

So:

> 101 would be replaced with 101-104-AAB,
> 337 would become 337-103-CAD (line 1) and 337-108-HHE (line 5), and
> 524 would become 524-204-DER?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was successful using the concatenation code from [Jamjitul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6681701/jamjitul) with `np.where()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file='insert path'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']] = df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']].astype(str)
dfseg=df['col_a']+'-'+df['col_b']+'-'+df['col_c']

df['col_d'] = np.where((df['col_a']=='101')|(df['col_a']=='337')|(df['col_a']=='524'),dfseg,df['col_a'])

df
```

generating this list:

|  | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | 104 | AAB | 101-104-AAB |
| 1 | 337 | 103 | CAD | 337-103-CAD |
| 2 | 524 | 204 | DER | 524-204-DER |
| 3 | 129 | 404 | EEH | 129 |
| 4 | 842 | 108 | HHR | 842 |
| 5 | 337 | 108 | HHE | 337-108-HHE |

Other options for capturing the OR conditions (currently separated by `|` above) are summarized [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-create-conditional-column-in-dataframe/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']] = df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']].astype(str)
df['col_a'] + '-' + df['col_b'] + '-' + df['col_c']
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. The concatenation was successful in generating the list, i.e. 0    101-104-AAB
1    337-103-CAD, etc. however I am trying to index the first 3 characters against the original list to replace, but could not... any way to maintain the original 'col_a" within the new dtype: object?